# ASP.NET WSAT (Website Administration Tool) and Custom Membership Providers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, wsat

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC applicaiton that  will have custom role and membership providers.  I have been looking into adminstration tools to save us some time, [WSAT](http://www.codeplex.com/AspNetWSAT) has crossed my path.  It looks good at a glance, it's all open source and very simple if it doesn't work I can fix it myself.

First question is have any of you used WSAT for a product system in the past.  Is it worth while, should I consider it and what reasons are there for not using it?

Second question, does anyone know how well WSAT works with custom providers?

Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: did it actually setup nice and work well?

Comment: i found setup simple and it worked. there are some items which could be improved like making it easier to turn captcha on/off and custom properties but better than i could put together :)

Comment: WSAT is not in CodePlex anymore

Comment: @Eduardo - It is now..  Check the "EDIT" to my answer below!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[MVC WSAT](http://wsat.codeplex.com/) appears to be the tool of choice for providing Web site Administration functionality to ASP.NET MVC web sites.

Also, although the ASPNetWSAT tool is no longer available on Codeplex, it is still available in places.  See this thread: [ASP.Net WSAT (Web Site Administration) Starter Kit. What happened?](http://forums.asp.net/p/1390061/3415574.aspx) and check the last post!

To address your specific question, the MyWSAT tool is fairly well written and robust, and has been used by quite a few people within their own websites (many people were quite upset when it was removed from Codeplex!).  Short of writing your own website administration tool, or paying for a commercial component, it's about the best out there.

The MVC WSAT tool is a rewrite of the original MyWSAT tool, made specifically for ASP.NET MVC-developed websites, and MVC WSAT should be used instead of MyWSAT for MVC sites.

**EDIT:**
Since approximately April of 2010, the MyWSAT project has been made available again by the original author on Codeplex!

Get it here:  http://mywsat.codeplex.com/

Comment: This query might be a bit old, but thanks for the informative answer.

Comment: @Odd - Agreed.  However, I've also looked for this tool myself and been disappointed to discover it no longer exists on Codeplex.  Finding a copy of the source code somewhere was a major plus, so I thought I'd share that here since many devs are still using ASP.NET 2.0 and developing non-MVC sites.

Comment: It looks to me like mvc wsat is a much more basic wrapper for asp.net admin functions than is MyWsat.  MyWsat is pretty full-featured.  MVC WSAT appears to be just getting started and definitely lacks the really nice look and feel of MyWsat.  Would love to se an actual port of MyWsat to MVC.