# List and manage users on webpage from ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am using VS2005 C#.

I would like to know if there is any guide which provides step by step instructions on providing a similar GUI on a webpage from the ASP.NET Web Administration Tool in managing AD users. E.g. editng user roles

Basically I wish to *transfer* ASP.NET Web Admin Tool to my web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is not really straight forward to create a custom WSAT in your application. But there are many options you have.

[ASP.NET WSAT (Website Administration Tool) and Custom Membership Providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160488/asp-net-wsat-website-administration-tool-and-custom-membership-providers)

or you can implement you own

https://web.archive.org/web/20210306174425/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/052307-1.aspx

this is also a good project on codeplex relation to this

http://mywsat.codeplex.com/

Hope this could help..