# Need help setting up Membership with ASP.NET MVC4/jQuery Mobile

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-membership, membership, wsat

I'm trying to figure out the best solution to integrate user authentication into my ASP.NET MVC4 web app.  I'm not familiar at all with ASP.NET membership providers.  What I ultimately want to be able to do is have the user be able to log in to access the app- pretty straight forward, right?  I've heard about WSAT, and how wonderful it is.  I want to be able to administer the log-in part of the site, kind of like what WSAT offers, so I can manage the user accounts.  What's the best and/or easiest solution to accomplish this?

One more question:

If I'm using CodeFirst in my project:

1. How will WSAT impact my database?  Will it cause any kind of problems?
2. Should I stick with a CodeFirstMembership provider?

Comment: Please have a look at :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160488/asp-net-wsat-website-administration-tool-and-custom-membership-providers?rq=1